# Read .sph files in Python

Tags: python, audio

I am working on a project where I need to extract the Mel-Cepstral Frequency Coefficients (MFCC) from audio signals. The first step for this process is to read the audio file into Python.

The audio files I have are stored in a .sph format. I am unable to find a method to read these files directly into Python. I would like to have the sampling rate, and a NumPy array with the data, similar to how wav read works.

Since the audio files I will be dealing with are large in size, I would prefer not to convert to .wav format for reading. Could you please suggest a possible method to do so?

Comment: .sph isn't a very common format, so I do believe that you are better off converting to .wav as you have decided, as libraries that do what you want probably don't exist, meaning you would have to write one (please don't do that to yourself). A Python .sph->.wav conversion library was actually one of the first things that popped up while I was researching this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was against converting to a .wav file as I assumed it would take a lot of time. That is not the case. So, converting using SoX suited my needs.

The following script when run in a windows folder converts all the files in that folder to a .wav file.

```
cd %~dp0
for %%a in (*.sph) do sox "%%~a" "%%~na.wav"
pause
```

After this, the following command can be used to read the file.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
(rate,sig) = wav.read("file.wav")
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50763111/11993595,), I was able to read a `.sph` file with [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html), as it can read everything that `audioread` and `ffmpeg` can read.

```
import librosa
import librosa.display # You need this in librosa to be able to plot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clip_dir = os.path.join("..","babel","LDC2016S10.sph") 
audio,sr = librosa.load(clip_dir,sr=16000) # audio is a numpy array

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
librosa.display.waveshow(audio, sr=sr, ax=ax) 
ax.set(title="LDC2016S10.sph waveform")
```

[image: Waveform of the .sph file]

Comment: I don't believe that this is a me too post, I hereby describe a way to read the mentioned file

Comment: Mea culpa, reading it again you are correct and I was wrong, maybe update answer with better details about librosa

Comment: It would be great if you added a simple example of reading the file with librosa

Comment: I hope it is better now :)

Comment: Now you have high quality post, keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read sph files via `audioread`with `ffmpeg` codecs.